# Azure Digital Twin Python API- Created Twin of Model but cannot retrieve it

Tags: python, azure, azure-digital-twins

I have succesfully created a twin of a model using the `azure.digitaltwins.core.DigitalTwinsClient` with the `upsert_digital_twin()` method returning an object like below (printed as dictionary):

```
{
    $dtId twin-spc4-4b670a8e-86ec-41b0-84a2-ce092578a0f6
    $etag W/"8c491e49-f81f-4c30-b189-1bd45f122d7c"
    area {'$metadata': {}}
    capacity {'$metadata': {}}
    occupancy {'$metadata': {}}
    temperature {'$metadata': {}}
    humidity {'$metadata': {}}
    CO2 {'$metadata': {}}
    $metadata {'$model': 'dtmi:digitaltwins:rec_3_3:core:Level;1'}
}
```

However when I try and get this model using the `get_digital_twin()` method I get the following error:

```
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: (DigitalTwinNotFound) There is no digital twin instance that exists with the ID {'$dtId': 'twin-spc4-4b670a8e-86ec-41b0-84a2-ce092578a0f6', '$etag': 'W%2F"8c491e49-f81f-4c30-b189-1bd45f122d7c"', 'area': {'$metadata': {}}, 'capacity': {'$metadata': {}}, 'occupancy': {'$metadata': {}}, 'temperature': {'$metadata': {}}, 'humidity': {'$metadata': {}}, 'CO2': {'$metadata': {}}, '$metadata': {'$model': 'dtmi:digitaltwins:rec_3_3:core:Level;1'}}. Please verify that the twin id is valid and ensure that the twin is not deleted. See section on querying the twins https://aka.ms/adtv2query.

Code: DigitalTwinNotFound
Message: There is no digital twin instance that exists with the ID {'$dtId': 'twin-spc4-4b670a8e-86ec-41b0-84a2-ce092578a0f6', '$etag': 'W%2F"8c491e49-f81f-4c30-b189-1bd45f122d7c"', 'area': {'$metadata': {}}, 'capacity': {'$metadata': {}}, 'occupancy': {'$metadata': {}}, 'temperature': {'$metadata': {}}, 'humidity': {'$metadata': {}}, 'CO2': {'$metadata': {}}, '$metadata': {'$model': 'dtmi:digitaltwins:rec_3_3:core:Level;1'}}. Please verify that the twin id is valid and ensure that the twin is not deleted. See section on querying the twins https://aka.ms/adtv2query.
```

What is happening? How can I retrieve the twin I created?

Comment: Can you see the created twin using [Azure Digital Twins Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-use-azure-digital-twins-explorer) ?

Comment: @asergaz No i can't see the twin in ADT Explorer. Weirdly I can query the twin via the API so it exists somewhere?

Comment: The team needs to look at internal logs, Create an Azure support request: https://aka.ms/iothelp

Comment: if you solved the issue in the support request can you share the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

after raising a support ticket, I was asked to run the query

```
SELECT * FROM digitaltwins T where T.$dtId = <model_identifier>
```

This worked and focused specifically on the node. Subsequently running

```
SELECT * FROM digitaltwins
```

showed all the nodes created.

My guess is the ADT explorer hadn't focused itself on the right node and that's why I couldn't see it.